# return regex results to an array

Tags: c#, regex, arrays

I'm working on a little project and this is my first time using regex

I've tried using .match or .matches but i don't see any option that will alow me to return the results of a regex query to an array.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you need an array? The MatchCollection returned by ".Matches" is not enough?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it but something like that will do the job :

```
public static IEnumerable<Match> GetMatches(Regex regex, string input)
{
    var m = regex.Match(input);
    while (m.Success)
    {
        yield return m;

        m = m.NextMatch();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error: cannot be an iterator block because 'IEnumerable<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>' is not an iterator interface type

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me. I use it like this :

   var re = new Regex(@"download");
   foreach (var m in GetMatches(re, @"download download download download"))
   {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
   } and it prints 4 times the string "download".

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Regex.Matches(input,regex,regexoptions)` it will return a collection of matches that you can then iterate through.

A collection is seen as a better thing to use for developing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2604h5s(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Matches CopyTo method to copy to the array of your choice.

Have a look at this

[MatchCollection.CopyTo Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.copyto.aspx)

Edit to comment

Something like this

```
Regex rg = new Regex("YourExpression");
MatchCollection matcheCollection = rg.Matches("Your String");
Match[] matches = new Match[matcheCollection.Count];
matcheCollection.CopyTo(matches, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess I'm confused as to why i can't go directly to a string[] rather than jumping through hoops with matches.  If my regex has (...) in it should it not be returning matches as string text?  thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex rg = new Regex("YourExpression");

Match[] result = rg.Matches("Your String").OfType<Match>().ToArray();
```

Would save you from having to define the Match[] separably.

Answer (score 1):

To return the matches of Regex as an array of Strings, you can do this.

```
    string[] stringArray; // this this will become our String array,

    Regex regex = new Regex(@"<your regex goes here>");
    List <String> listTemp = new List<string>();
    foreach (Match matchItem in regex.Matches(<your string to spit/match>))
    {
       listTemp.Add(matchItem.ToString());
    }
    stringArray = listTemp.ToArray<String>();
```

Hope this helps!